# Working with Opencv Sobel results

Tags: opencv, roi

I use OpenCV `cvSobel ()` to find vertical lines inside image - it works good. But don't understand, possible or not to work with Sobel results? I need get demention (height) of some founded same vertical lines and, if it found more than 5 same vertical lines (going from left to right) - create ROI that have height demention and coordinates that depend of founded lines height.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [HoughLines function.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) It detects lines in an image. I recommend you DO use the Sobel method, possibly in conjunction with Threshold or AdaptiveThreshold (in that case, use HoughLinesP)

Another (roi-like) alternative is by using FindCountours after Sobel and Thresholding. You can use the countours' bounding boxes to create RoI's.